# cannot link to vtk 6.3 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkCommon

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, linker-errors, vtk

I installed vtk 6.3 from source and I am trying to compile my project using the following cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)

project      (paintsquad)
find_package (Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core)
find_package (VTK 6.3 REQUIRED)
find_package (PCL 1.8.0 REQUIRED)

include_directories (/usr/local/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories (${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories    (${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions     (${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

...

QT5_WRAP_CPP (project_HEADERS_MOC   ${project_HEADERS})
QT5_WRAP_UI  (project_FORMS_HEADERS ${project_FORMS})

ADD_DEFINITIONS (${QT_DEFINITIONS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE  (pcl_visualizer ${project_SOURCES}
                                ${project_FORMS_HEADERS}
                                ${project_HEADERS_MOC}
                                ${project_hpp_files})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (pcl_visualizer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
qt5_use_modules (pcl_visualizer Widgets)
```

But I'm getting these linker errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkCommon
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkFiltering
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkImaging
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGraphics
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGenericFiltering
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkIO
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRendering
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkVolumeRendering
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkHybrid
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkWidgets
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkInfovis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkGeovis
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkViews
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkCharts
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I had previously installed vtk 5.8 from source, so now I have to installations.
I'm using ubuntu 16.

Comment: I believe the libraries are different with vtk-6.

Comment: I checked and all the vtk 6.3 .so files are in /usr/local/lib

Comment: I think I may have to use vtk 5.8 at the end and compile it with qt4. Since I compiled pcl with vtk 5.8 :/

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I had compiled pcl previously with vtk version 5.8 and was trying to use vtk version 6.3, which I had installed later.

So I solved this by first deleting my vtk 5.8 and then recompiling pcl with vtk version 6.3.